# Retrieving data from different classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm having trouble with access methods and parameters using different classes, I used to code with Java so I have no issues to use functions of another scopes.

```
class Ball;
class Canvas4 {

public:
    static const int num = 100;
    vector<Ball> ballCollection;
    Ball *myBall;
    Ball getBallById(int id) {
        return this->ballCollection.at(id)
    };      
};

class Ball {
    friend class Canvas4;
public:
    void lineBetween() {
        for (int i=0; i<Canvas4::num; i++) {
            Ball other = Canvas4::ballCollection.at(i);
            //*Invalid use of non-static data member "ballCollection"
        }
    };    
};
```

*Invalid use of non-static data member "ballCollection"

I want to read the content of certain Ball Object by Id and draw some art with it.

**EDIT**

On another class I did.

```
#include "canvas4.h" //which contains both classes Ball and Canvas4

Canvas4 canvas4;
```

Comment: Just like in Java, you need an instance of class `Canvas4` before you can access its non-static members.

Comment: I instatiate Canvas4 canvas4; In main class.

Comment: So pass a reference to that instance as a parameter to `lineBetween`, or something along these lines. There may be multiple canvasses in the program; how else is `lineBetween` supposed to know whose ball collection it should be looking at?

Comment: '::' parameter is used to access static methods of a class. If you want to invoke a method of an object you need to use '.' operator and your object is named with lowercase letter not uppercase

Answer (score 0):

You need a class object of type Canvas4 to use the non-static member function in class Ball.
Only member functions having qualifier as static in a class can be used in "Class::Function" format.

**EDIT**

```
class Ball {
public:

    Canvas4 *cv;
    Ball(ofVec2f _org, ofVec2f _loc, float _radius, int _dir, float _offSet, Canvas4 *_cv):
    org(_org),loc(_loc),radius(_radius), dir(_dir), offSet(_offSet),cv(_cv){}

void Ball::lineBetween() {
    for (int i=0; i<Canvas4::num; i++) {
        Ball other = cv->getBallById(i);
        float distance = loc.distance(other.loc);
        if (distance >0 && distance < d) {
            ofLine(loc.x, loc.y, other.loc.x, other.loc.y);
        }
    }
}
};
```

It is necessary that you intilaize class variables in the constructor as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, static members of a class are accessed by applying `::` on the class name, and non-static members by `.` on an object of the class, e.g.

```
struct A
{
   int x;
   static int y;
};

void f(A a)
{
   a.x = 1;
   A::y = 2;
};
```

You are trying to access `ballCollection` as if it was a static member, which it is not.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that I found using the suggestion by @Igor was simply insert a pointer to Canvas at Ball class:

```
class Ball {
public:

    Canvas4 *cv;
    Ball(ofVec2f &_org, ofVec2f &_loc, float _radius, int _dir, float _offSet, Canvas4 &_cv);

void Ball::lineBetween() {
    for (int i=0; i<Canvas4::num; i++) {
        Ball other = cv->getBallById(i);
        float distance = loc.distance(other.loc);
        if (distance >0 && distance < d) {
            ofLine(loc.x, loc.y, other.loc.x, other.loc.y);
        }
    }
}
};
```